# Write to file with Frida instead write to console.log

Tags: frida

With Frida, I know how to write to `console.log` like:

```
console.log('TARGETED_METHOD_CALLED');
```

But how can I write to a file?

Comment: https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#file

Comment: @0xec I have tried `f = new File("/tmp/logger", "wb")` But I got error `Error: failed to open file (No such file or directory)` (even this file really exist) I want this logger file will be into my ubuntu , not into android ,yes?

Comment: Are you using Frida on a samartphone (iOS/Android) or an local application? If you use it for a smartphone then the question is where do you want to write the file on the smartphone or on the connected PC?

Comment: @Robert I use frida-server into Android and frida in Ubuntu , I want to save the logger file into my Ubuntu

Comment: Please edit your question and add this important info + tagging. Then you can't do this in frida JavaScript as the JS code is executed on Android side. You can only use [send()](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#communication-send) on client side but the you have to implement python code on server side to handle those sent messages.